# Rationale for global variables stored in "data section" instead of stack?

Tags: static, global-variables, cpu-architecture, stack-memory

Global variables could be stored at the top of the stack analogous to a local variable that just never gets deleted except when program ends. But this requires incrementing the stack pointer for each global variable, even though they will never use the stack pointer (because the stack will never grow or shrink in that region, it is persistent scope throughout program runtime. ) Is the rationale for placing these variables instead in a different section (that has to be added separately in the CPU architecture, adding some complexity since it is another part) that they simply do not need the mechanisms built-in to the stack (stack pointer specifically)? Historically, was a separate "global variable section" added in early-on, or did computers use the top of the stack (or bottom, depending on design and what way it is incremented) for that?

Comment: How would functions find them without a pointer to them, if they weren't at a known absolute address?  (and known offset relative to the .text section for ISAs like x86-64 where PC-relative addressing is more efficient.)  Laying out process images in memory is just software, not CPU architecture.  The CPU doesn't need any special support, it just has to be able to dereference pointers in registers; e.g. MIPS only has one addressing mode, `imm16 + register`, and the ability to generate an arbitrary 32-bit value in a register in a couple instructions.

Comment: OK I might have misunderstood the stack. I assumed nested functions could access the above function. Even though in higher level programming I know that is usually not the case. I guess a follow-up question I have would be: why do stack frames not tend to be able to read stack frames one scope up (or more)? I don't see directly why that limitation has been decided on, seems like they could read outside the frame the same way they read inside the frame.

Comment: They can, but they wouldn't know the right offset to access anything specific.  A compiler (or human) is free to lay out local vars in any order they want, potentially even with runtime-variable amounts of extra space (e.g. alloca or C99 VLAs).  And they don't know what chain of calls reached them, e.g. a recursive function accessing a global has to access the same location for the global when called with different stack-pointer values.  Or a function that's called from multiple other call sites with different depths and stack-frame sizes in the parents.

Comment: Historically on some machines, globals at absolute addresses were better supported by the ISA than accessing data relative to a stack pointer, so if you didn't need re-entrancy, local vars could get changed to global / static.  e.g. 8-bit micros often didn't have good support for locals in stack memory.  See [Why do C to Z80 compilers produce poor code?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6095) for some details.  Even more ancient machines also tended to use absolute addresses, like http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/story-of-mel.html / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Story_of_Mel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global data variables go in the data section almost by definition.  All the features you would want — initialized data like strings literals, other constants, arrays, etc.. (pre-initialized if you will, by the loader from the program file's data section, i.e. rather than by executing program code), being able to take the address of data within that initialized data (data initialized as pointer to other data), same for code being able to refer to data, labels in data that are constants, ["common" data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable#Global-only_and_global-by-default), etc..

---

> Historically, was a separate "global variable section" added in early-on, or did computers use the top of the stack (or bottom, depending on design and what way it is incremented) for that?

Historically, the data sections came first, and computers did not have stacks.  Stacks were only added later as the acceptance for recursion became prominent in software, and hardware design followed software evolution.  (In much older systems, code & data went together in a combined program "core"
image.)

As mentioned above, these data sections support initialized data, a necessity for even the most early programming.  There has never been a reason for the stack to support these capabilities, given the (global) data section already does.

---

> I assumed nested functions could access the above function.

If by nested functions you mean statically nested (e.g. enclosed/embedded; functions that are defined within the scope of another function), that can be done provided the runtime function call mechanism provides for a "static link" that refers to the enclosing scope.  Languages like Pascal have this.  (The static link is passed as a hidden parameter, much like `this` in OOP languages.)

In Pascal, this mechanism mixes access to dynamic call chain, with access to  enclosing function's local variables.  It allows for a sort of poor man's object model, in which during lifetime of the function, it is almost as if an "object" is created from its local variables — on the stack — and functions nested with that scope can access the enclosing scope's local variables, similar to objects — but this is an object that disappears when the outer scope completes.  (The more general object mechanism of OOP languages doesn't mandate the object be removed when the outer scope leaves, and also allows those objects to be first class — referenced explicitly rather than only implicitly.)

If by nested function you are referring to the dynamic call chain alone, access to caller's variables would usually be supplied as reference parameters of some sort — this, in particular, since in this scenario, the callee doesn't know which caller, so letting the caller provide appropriate parameters that relate to the intent of that particular caller makes sense there.

---

> Why do stack frames not tend to be able to read stack frames one scope up

They can access those memory locations, just isn't supported by a number of popular languages.  In order to make sense of how to access variables belonging to the caller, we have to provide extra runtime support.  As I mentioned, Pascal provides a model for doing this; these are broadly referred using the term "non-local" (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-local_variable).

Comment: OK I think I get it. The addresses of the local variables pushed to the stack are known relative to the stack pointer. Since "the callee doesn't know which caller", like you wrote, if two separate functions were to call the same function, it could not know which was the caller, or where the local variables in the caller would be relative to the stack pointer.

Comment: That's correct, so for those scenarios most languages offer some form of reference parameters allowing a caller to bind local variables (or heap variables, or its own reference parameters) as actual arguments to the formal parameters of the callee.  The callee can then work in terms those formal parameters without further knowledge of the caller.

Comment: For the Pascal-style nested functions, you can declare nested functions and they do have knowledge of the caller's local variables and their layout with the stack frame, and, the nested function cannot be invoked without first invoking the outer scoped function, so there always is an outer function for a nested function to refer to. ...

Comment: ... The outer scoped function, though, isn't necessarily the immediate caller of a nested function (nested functions can recurse, as well as there being multiple nested functions), but the outer scope function is on the stack somewhere.  The static link mechanism provides nested functions with a pointer to a table of enclosing scopes so it can find those scopes and their stack frames, and given that and their built in knowledge of the local variable layout in their stack frames can access those non-local variables.